# How to solve this question using approximation theory?

Tags: approximation, approximation-theory

I am asked to find the first three terms in the taylor series of the function

$$
f(x)=(x-1)\ln x
$$

around $x_0=0$.

Then to find the maximum error in my approximation in the interval $[0.5,1.5]$.

My question is how could I find the first three terms of the function since the first term is $f(x_0)=f(0)=\infty$

Comment: You are right, you can't. But given that the interval is $[0.5,1.5]$, one can suspect that $x_0=1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

From the well-known $$\ln(1+t)=t-\frac{t^2}2+\frac{t^3}3-\cdots,$$ you get that

$$(x-1)\ln(x)=(x-1)^2-\frac{(x-1)^3}2+\frac{(x-1)^4}3-\cdots$$

Comment: But, this is not the Taylor series or is it?

Comment: @mrdi: what else ?

Comment: But, why is it that when you use the definition of the Taylor series which is  the sum $\frac{f^{(n)}(x)x^{n}}{n!}$, you don't get the same answer?

Comment: You didn't read my former comment.

Comment: You mean the comment saying $what else ?" but I don't understand what you mean. Is it the Taylor series or not?

Comment: @MrDi, you should be using $\dfrac{f^{(n)}(x-1)^n}{n!}$.  Note that it's $(x-1)^n$, not $x^n$.

Comment: @MrDi I think Yves Daoust means his comment below the question. How could you have a Taylor series about $x=0$? The function is infinite at $x=0$. So he assumes you meant to ask for a Taylor series about $x=1$. If you did mean to ask about a Taylor series about $x=0$ then the answer would be different: there isn't one. If you meant to ask about $x=1$ it would stop confusion if you amended the question.